# TypeError: undefined is not a function - Angular Animate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, typeerror

I am getting an error when I load up my Angular App.-

```
"TypeError: undefined is not a function"
```

I have narrowed down the problem to having something to do with declaring ngAnimate in my controller as well as the error first being thrown in the Angular Animate file on line 504 -

```
var hasClass = angular.$$hasClass(element[0], className);
```

Here's a look at my controller.  Everything works the way I want it to even with ngAnimate included.

```
var tdfapp = angular.module('tdfapp', ['ngAnimate']);

tdfapp.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.users = [];

$http.get('user.json').success(function(data) {

angular.copy(data, $scope.users );

});

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are `ngAnimate` and angular the same version?

Comment: @ExplosionPills

Angular is
`v1.3.0-rc.0`
Angular Animate is
`v1.3.0-build.3227+sha.90cd1e0`

Comment: You may want to try using the same stable version for both instead of release candidate and unstable versions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I was using different versions of Angular and of Angular Animate.

Switches both to stable release of 1.2.9 and it solved the problem

Comment: I guess you should accept your answer. It helped me, too.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue but my Angular and Angular Animate versions match - both `1.3.8`. I'm curious if anyone else is having this problem or has found another solution?

Answer (score 0):

If using node - switching back to Node v7.8.0 (from v8.4.0) solved this problem.